# Laravel custom pagination, get count of records matching filters

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination

I use Laravel 5.5. I have a module that applies filters and makes pagination using _limit and _page (`offset=limit*(page-1)`). Example of request url:

```
api/v1/clients?firstname=John&active=true&_limit=10&_page=2
```

In this example I apply all filters in Query Builder and in response will be 10 records that match conditions `firstname=John and active=true` and will skip first 10 records because the page is 2. 
I need the count of records matching my filters for page numbers on front-end. Laravel pagination has a function for that:

`$q->paginate(10)->total();`

How to get the count of all matching records from my query builder if I don't use laravel paginate()?

Comment: `SomeModel::all()->count();` And in your case it could be `$q->count();`

Comment: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('table_name')->get()->count();`

Comment: We can use this function:
`$builder->getQuery()->getCountForPagination();`

Comment: you said you don't use laravel pagination i guess

Comment: The question is why don't you use the laravel paginator ?

Comment: I don't need all the data that paginate() add to the response, I only need the total count to know how to draw page navigation buttons

Comment: Then manipulate the return value of `paginate()` before sending it with the response. Still the paginator handling all the heavy lifting for you, I think is the best solution. Other option is extending the Laravel paginator with a custom implementation.

Comment: $count = $q->count();